# Django Parameters in URL from POST Request

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a search bar in Django, where users can enter a value to search for, click enter / search button, and then the url redirects to https:localhost:3000/usearch/abc, if they for example search for `abc`. This is URL paramter can always change based on the search, and it should send the parameter to the `views.py` file to be processed, though I can't get it to work.

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('register/', views.register, name='register'),
    path('usearch/', views.usearch, name='usearch'),
    path('usearch/<str:query>', views.usearch_query, name='usearch_query'
]
```

**views.py**

```
def usearch(request):
   return render(request, 'myapp/usearch.html')

def usearch_query(request, query):
   context = {'query': query}
   print(query) # Testing the search result
   return render(request, 'myapp/usearch_query.html'}
```

**usearch.html**

```
<form method="GET" action="{% url 'usearch_query' %}
   <input type="search" placeholder="Search here...">
   <button type="submit"> Search </button>
</form>
```

**usearch_query.html**

```
{{ query }}
```

I essentially want the user to search something, have it navigate to `usearch/<search_parameter>` and process the search in the `usearch_query` function so I can do some computations with it.

Comment: 1) You should avoid using POST for a search request. POST should be used for requests that change something, and can't be safely repeated. 2) You could do this either using JavaScript to change the action of the form, or by creating a server side redirect.

Comment: Thanks, updated. Is this not possible with just Django, I thought it was? Otherwise I'm not too sure how to do it with JS / server side redirects

Comment: You can use the redirect() function to redirect the user. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect

Comment: Worked great, thanks!